# How to customize URL search conditions on Google

Tags: google-search

I want to be able to tell Google

> if [some string] is in the URL, don't include as a search result

For example:

If I want to do a search for "popcorn", the first thing that comes up as a result is `www.thepopcornfactory.com`.  How can I tell it

> if 'popcorn' is in the URL, exclude that result

I checked the advanced search, couldn't find that option.  Anyone know a search engine that allows this?

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't seem to be possible with Google. In the paragraph about the `site` operator, [GoogleGuide](http://www.googleguide.com/advanced_operators.html#site) says,

> You can use many of the search
>   operators in conjunction with the
>   basic search operators +, –, OR, and "
>   ".

but it doesn't seem to work for the `inurl` operator.

The following works for one specific site:

```
popcorn -site:thepopcornfactory.com
```

You could string together all the sites you don't want (which is how I use it), but that's hardly optimal and only works on the domain name, not the entire `URL`:

```
popcorn -site:thepopcornfactory.com -site:popcornhour.com -site:popcorn.org
```

As partial domain matching [seems to be limited](http://googlecustomsearch.blogspot.com/2008/02/specifying-patterns-for-your-custom.html) even for Google's [Custom Search](http://www.google.com/cse/), I suspect that this might be a limitation of the way they keep or access their index. So above may be the only way, unless someone else knows more.

Answer (score 3):

Google allows this if the [string] you're trying to exclude needs to be excluded only when it occupies a whole "word" of the URL.  So for instance you can exclude thepopcornfactory.com sites with

> -inurl:thepopcornfactory

but that won't exclude *en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Popcorn* or *www.popcornopolis.com*.  Using:

> -inurl:popcorn

similarly won't exclude *thepopcornfactory.com* or *www.popcornopolis.com*