# Google's inurl option isn't working for this website

Tags: google-search

If I do  inurl:yahoo and search that, then yahoo comes up. So the inurl tag seems like it maybe works.

But it does't work for this website  https://www.solubilityofthings.com/

i.e. if I do  inurl:solubility

then nothing comes up

The website is indexed. Since if I google for solubilityofthings, then the website comes up.

Comment: What is the question? Related: [How to customize URL search conditions on Google](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/14993/88163), [Return all websites with specific keyword in base URL](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/148384/88163)

Comment: What of my question are you not understanding?  An example of a URL is you know, the one I gave in my question , that starts with http  So, `https://www.solubilityofthings.com/`    inurl is used by Google to specify a string in the URL. You know what that means? I can't make it simpler. So I've no idea what you aren't understanding. Could you clarify?

Comment: So I want a google search that brings up all URLs with the string `solubility` in them and it should bring up `https://www.solubilityofthings.com/`  Because if you look carefully, you will see it has the string `solubility` in it.  Is the question clear to you now?! If so, what part of the question wasn't clear to you?! And what i'm saying in the question is that what I tried, and that it didn't work. Maybe you need an image too, to help you understand. i'll try including that

Comment: @Rubén And to be fair, it's actually kind of working now.. though I think I want it in the domain part of the URL only.

Comment: Well, you might want to send your feedback directly to Google. At the bottom of the search results page is a "Send feedback" link.

Comment: @Rubén well I told you it's actually working now though doesn't cover "base URL" which is really what I want.

Comment: @Rubén I have sent them feedback about an inbaseurl  or inurlbase operator being useful.. doubt they'll do it but anyhow

Comment: They are the only who could do something to fix bugs and improve the product. Regarding the question, its wording needs some work and details like sharing what you found during your search and research efforts and why it didn't meet your needs. I suggest you to take a look to https://support.google.com/websearch to look at the most recent version of the article about the search operators.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that `inurl:` might be hard to be understood.

---

Unfortunately the docs from Google (websearch / [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)) Help Center articles that mentions search operators doesn't include `inurl:`

- [Refine web searches](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433)
- [Do an Advanced Search on Google](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/35890?hl=en)

There are a lot of recent content generated by "creators" that still mentions `inurl:`. I haven't found yet one that cites properly a recent canonical source. Several years ago [Matt Cutts](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matt_Cutts) was the "canonical source", but he no longers works in Google.  Here is one blog article from this personal blog about inurl from the time when he still was part of Google ->  [SEO advice: interpreting inurl](https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/seo-advice-interpreting-inurl/) from 2006.

It looks that current "Search Advocate" is John Mueller (based in  https://io.google/2022/speakers/john-mueller/). I haven't found a post authored by him but there are a lot of videos, interviews and postes quoting him. Some still mentions  `inurl:` like [10 Of Web’s Most Common SEO Myths (And Why They’re Wrong)](https://wpdailycoupons.com/most-common-seo-myths-and-why-theyre-wrong/) from June 17, 2022.

Related

- [How to exclude a domain from Google search?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/9707/88163)
- [How to customize URL search conditions on Google](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/14993/88163)
- [Excluding all URLs containing a specific word](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/27039/88163)
- [Searching Google for files and pages which contain .something](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/28909/88163)

Answer (score 0):

The `inurl` tag works. Google searches a huge index of web pages in an effort to return pages that meet your search criteria, in order of relevance (which they define). Tags like `inurl` are a tool used to help restrict that search.

When you search `inurl:yahoo` Google returns Yahoo!'s website for your locale as the first result which reflects that site's relative ranking among the results.

But, if you were to search instead for
`inurl:yahoo -site:yahoo.com` you would get results that excluded yahoo.com. For example,

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!
- https://www.facebook.com/yahoo/
- https://downdetector.ca/status/yahoo/
- https://www.yahoo-inc.com/

Typing `inurl:solubility` turns up a large number of sites with `solubility` in the URL ordered according to Googles's algorithm. For example,

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solubility
- https://chemistrytalk.org/what-is-solubility/
- https://www.britannica.com/science/solubility-chemistry
- https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/biochemistry-genetics-and-molecular-biology/solubility
- https://www.chem.fsu.edu/chemlab/chm1046course/solubility.html

Searching for `inurl:solubilityofthings` likewise turns up sites with `solubilityofthings` in the URL. For example,

- https://www.solubilityofthings.com/
- https://www.accessify.com/s/solubilityofthings.com
- https://www.sitelike.org/similar/solubilityofthings.com/