# how do i search for a specific path amongst all websites?

Tags: google-search, search-engine

in google, i know i can search specific contents of a site by going `site:example.com`

I want to search the whole world, but for specific paths. for example,

```
site:*.com/CustomPath
```

or

```
anysite.com/SomePath/MyownPath
```

I want to return all websites that have /SomePath/MyownPath links for example in their paths. Can this be done ?

Comment: Have you tried the advanced search? https://www.google.com/advanced_search

Comment: so i need to pick, `url` of the page and for exact term to search fill my custom path, ? @GeneMoody-Action1

Comment: if you cannot find it by the "exact word" you can use the inurl: modifier in the search as well https://ahrefs.com/blog/google-advanced-search-operators/ or combination thereof.

Answer (score 1):

Try   `inurl`. i.e. `inurl:something`

It's not clear that this be accurate regarding returning paths having `/` (hierarchical structure, folder / subfolder).

Related

- [Google's inurl option isn't working for this website](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/169236/88163)

Reference

- [Narrow your search with operators](https://support.google.com/cloudsearch/answer/6172299?hl=en)